# Checkbox in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

How to improve the space between Flex Checkbox and it's label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following style property:

> horizontalGap - Gap between the label
>   and icon, when the labelPlacement
>   property is set to left or right. The
>   default value is 2.

Link: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html#style:horizontalGap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html#style%3ahorizontalGap)

Comment: Is Their is any chance to increase the default value ?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to change it on every checkbox. You can make a css-class in which you set the horizontalGap and assign this class to the Checkbox with `stylename="..."`